# Select products by total price in the most efficient way possible

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables to which I added some data:

```
create table dbo.Products
(
  Id int identity not null primary key clustered (Id),  
  Name nvarchar (120) not null,
  Price decimal (19,4) not null
);

create table dbo.AllowedQuantities
(
  Id int identity not null primary key clustered (Id),  
  Quantity float not null
);

create table dbo.ProductsAllowedQuantities
(
  ProductId int not null, 
  QuantityId int not null,
    constraint ProductIdQuantityId primary key clustered (ProductId, QuantityId)
);

alter table dbo.ProductsAllowedQuantities
add constraint CProductId foreign key (ProductId) references Products(Id),
    constraint CQuantityId foreign key (QuantityId) references AllowedQuantities(Id);

insert into dbo.AllowedQuantities (Quantity) VALUES (0.5), (1), (2)

insert into dbo.Products (Name, Price) VALUES ('A', 400), ('B', 500), ('C', 800), ('D', 1000), ('E', 1200), ('F', 1400)

insert into dbo.ProductsAllowedQuantities (ProductId, QuantityId) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2)
insert into dbo.ProductsAllowedQuantities (ProductId, QuantityId) VALUES (2, 1)
insert into dbo.ProductsAllowedQuantities (ProductId, QuantityId) VALUES (3, 1), (3, 3)
insert into dbo.ProductsAllowedQuantities (ProductId, QuantityId) VALUES (4, 2), (4, 3)
insert into dbo.ProductsAllowedQuantities (ProductId, QuantityId) VALUES (5, 1), (5, 3)
insert into dbo.ProductsAllowedQuantities (ProductId, QuantityId) VALUES (6, 2)
```

I used the following query:

```
select p.Name, p.Price, aq.Quantity, TotalPrice = p.Price * aq.Quantity
from dbo.Products as p
join dbo.ProductsAllowedQuantities as paq
on p.Id = paq.ProductId
join dbo.AllowedQuantities aq
on paq.QuantityId = aq.Quantity
```

And got the following data:

[image]

**NOTE 1**
It is strange that Quantity = 0.5 does not appear ... What am I missing?

**THE OBJECTIVE**

1. Given the total prices TP = { 700, 1900 } I need to find one random product for each one.
2. For each total price given I set a range of +/- 200. So the ranges are:
   700 > [500, 900]
   1900 > [1700, 2100]
3. Looking at the table I see values that qualifies for these:

   700 > [500, 900] > Rows 2 to 4
   1900 > [1700, 2100] > Row 5
4. So I would pick one random row of 2 to 4 and row 5.

**NOTE 2**
When possible I would like each selection to contain a different row.

So if the solution would be:

700 > [500, 900] > Rows 2 to 4
   1900 > [1700, 2100] > Rows 4 and 5

If row 4 would be selected I would like to be selected only once.

I am not sure if this is possible ...

So I am looking for the most efficiency way to do this.

And to improve my database by changing the scheme if that is necessary or adding some indexes ...

Comment: It seems like you are giving us a set of requirements and asking us to write the query for you.  I would suggest giving it your best shot, doing some basic performance tuning if you run into slowness and then come back here with a specific question regarding performance if you are still having problems.

Comment: Besides defining what you need... [have you tried anything](http://whathaveyoutried.com) to solve the problem?

Comment: I am creating a full example with T-SQL. Will update my question soon.

Comment: I just updated my question with code and data ... I also added the query I am using to find the available total price for each product but I am not sure how to filter it ...

Answer (score -1):

The database scheme is pretty fine. You may have to add some indices, but I can't see any way to improve the database schema for more efficiency.

It should be no big deal to query a handful rows, so I don't think, you have even worry about efficiency.

Comment: Your query can't be more efficent that the number of result rows. So - if you have thousands of products, you either have to query thousands of products (and can't be more efficient), or you can limit the results (by using LIMIT ...). 

But efficiencyy is a question of complexity. Will you have unneccessary table scans, or a highly optimized query?

If you provide me your suggested query, I can tell you, if some indices are necessary to improve the efficiency. 
However, I can't see any chance to improve the **database scheme** for further efficiency improvements.

Comment: @MDMoura: that is funny - you completely rephrased your question after my answer.

Comment: @theo I didn't chance it ... I improved my question as asked.